# Popup with multiple information different tabs

Tags: leaflet, html

I have a lot of information that I want to show on a Leaflet Popup. In my case I have a GeoJSON file with different points. However in my case one point represent the same location, but it was collected 5 different attributes for that same point.

I want to show them as tabs inside the Popup, i.e., in one point I have 5 tabs with different information. Something like these:

[image]

I create a function that is called by L.geojson.ajax:

```
function returnVector(json, latlng){
               var att = json.properties;
               return L.circleMarker(latlng, {radius:3, color:'blue'}).bindPopup(
                "<div style='background:PeachPuff;width: 400px; height: 400px'><b>"+ "<p>Sample Number: "+ att.Sample_nr + "</p><p>Spectrum Number: "+ att.Spectrum_n +"</p><p>Face Color: "+ att.Face_color +"</p><p>Face Type: "+ att.Face_type +"</p><p>Sample_description: "+ att.Sample_des+"</p><p>Spectral_m: "+ att.Spectral_m  + "</p><img src='" + "/img/" + att.Photo + "'/>"+ "<img src='" + "/img/" + att.Spectra_ab + "'/>",{
  maxWidth: "auto"
});
```

Everything works fine, except I do not have the 5 different information associated to one point as I want to have.

Is there any way to put the information on tabs or with an arrow that allows to change between the information?

Comment: @TomazicM unfortunately no. It is the same doubt and I comment it explaining that I try the code proposed. However I did not get any answer to solve the question.

Comment: What do you get when using the code? Or maybe you should share a minimal working example including the code in the question. I don't think anyone would bother to write the code from scratch to find what the problem is.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code of what you have tried. In the duplicate there is working CodePen, so it should work for you.

Comment: @TomazicM it works in CodePen, but without CSS, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b54Er.png).

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz OK, I get the point, answer is not complete in itself. I'll edit it and add necessary CSS definitions.